# How To Deploy Admin Block Extension To Store

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm following the docs of Admin block extension to custom the UI of Admin customer detail, I can preview this app but can't deploy this app to my store.
When I run the deploy command:
npm run deploy

I got an error: extensions.targeting: Block extension is in developer preview and cannot be deployed to production stores.

I checked the docs and it says: "Admin blocks are in developer preview and can't be deployed to production versions of your app."
So I have a confused: If I cannot deploy this app to my store, how can I add and customize the UI of admin in production environment. If cannot, is another way to customize the Admin UI?

Any suggestions or recommendation?
Thanks in advance.

When I run the deploy command:
npm run deploy

I got an error: extensions.targeting: Block extension is in developer preview and cannot be deployed to production stores.

I checked the docs and it says: "Admin blocks are in developer preview and can't be deployed to production versions of your app."
So I have a confused: If I cannot deploy this app to my store, how can I add and customize the UI of admin in production environment. If cannot, is another way to customize the Admin UI?

Comment: This mean this currently not available to public use, when it gone live then you able to use the same into public live apps

Comment: @Onkar Could you please tell me more in detail, I don't have a clue

Comment: This feature is currently is development phase, and you can't use it on live websites until the same is release to all.

Comment: Do you  have any suggestions?

Comment: for what......?

Comment: We wanna use Shopify products and add attributes to them, but as you said it's not possible with admin blocks, Are there other ways to add attributes to products using an extension or our Shopify API or sth?